# Most affordable/quick method to block light through windows?

Tags: windows

I've got a door pane and a few small windows I want to cover up but I'm not certain what tools exist.  Blinds and curtains require too much time and cost.  Are there any easy to use paper-type tool to quickly cover up to block light? It needs to be light too as I have no transportation access.

I have access to a Canadian Tire if that helps.

Edit: Anything a bit aesthetically pleasing that doesn't leave sticky traces?

Edit 2: To save time is there anything such as a self-stick sheets that doesn't leave residue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not a fan of cardboard or aluminum foil, there are pleated paper shades that are very cheap and just use tape for install.  An example is [here](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/redi-shade-paper-window-shades/1010849217) and [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000SDX54M).  These can usually be found at big box hardware stores and any other large home goods stores.

Edit based on comment
Option 2

Go to a fabric store and pick out a dark/heavy fabric.  Hang it up with a couple of nails.  If you need to draw them back during the day, tie them into a bunch with some string, rope or scrap fabric.

Comment: Shadows can seen theough those.  Need something that blocks light.

Answer (score 6):

Cardboard,

[image: cardboard]

and tape.

[image: tape]

Probably the cheapest option, as you can probably acquire the cardboard for free.

Comment: I was going to say aluminum foil, but cardboard is probably cheaper.

Comment: Actually did think of these but I want something aesthetically okay too.

Comment: @verve A bit of paint, crayons, markers, etc. would help with aesthetics.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk I was going to buy this but I didn't want the neighbours to think I was a weirdo. It's a million-dollar neighbourhood. One of THOSE neighbourhoods where stuff is "policied". I don't want to indirectly ruin the aesthetic & look ghetto. lol.

Comment: @verve Sorry. When it comes to keeping things looking nice, I let my wife make all the aesthetic choices... I'm just glad I still pick out my own clothes... On that note, some butcher paper and some good quality masking tape (the blue kind) that doesn't leave residue might work. Even the inside of brown paper grocery bags would be a though.

Comment: Where can I buy few sheets of butcher paper?  Is that like Kraft paper? Does it block light? Do you think Scotch tape (office green boxed kind) work?